# Why doesn't my if / else statement work properly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am trying to iterate through the arrays in the numbers variable, and if a number can be divided by 3 I'm logging "fizz", if it can be divided by 5 I'm logging "buzz", and if a number can be divided by 3 + 5, or 15, I'm logging "fizzbuzz"

Here is the working code:

```
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
for (var i = 1; i <= numbers.length; i++) {  
    if (i % 15 === 0) {
        console.log("FizzBuzz");
    } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
        console.log("Buzz");
    } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
        console.log("Fizz");
    } else {
        console.log(i);
    }
};
```

Here is my original code, which doesn't log "fizzbuzz"

```
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
for (var i = 1; i <= numbers.length; i++) {      
    if (i % 5 === 0) {
        console.log("Buzz");
    } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
        console.log("Fizz");
    } else if (i % 15 === 0) {
        console.log("FizzBuzz");
    } else {
        console.log(i);
    }
};
```

Why does the (i % 15 === 0) condition need to precede the other two conditions? Shouldn't it not matter?

Comment: When using if and else together once one condition are true the others aren't checked, so in your case 15 % 5 == 0 is true, so it don't have to check other conditions.

If you were not using else, only ifs you would get Buzz, Fizz and FizzBuzz as result because without an else all the ifs would be true when the value were 15.

Comment: Why do you have an array if you are not using it? Make sure that you are not missing it, otherwise delete it and replace it with an `int` to set the iteration limit.

Comment: Ahh yeah the question asked to have an array, or more specifically, had the word "array" in it so my n00b brain put an array...but I definitely could have gotten away with just the for loop to print out numbers 1 ~ 20

Wow I need to learn to think outside the box much much better lol

Answer (score 3):

The number 15 is divisible by both 3 and 5. If you don't test it first, then you'll never get there.

So let's take 30 as an example. If you check 15 first, you'll see that it's divisible by 15. However, if you check either 5 or 3 first, it'll be flagged as being divisible by either of those.

Comment: Holy crap how the heck did I miss that...must have been staring at the code for way too long

Edit: I tried to upvote you but I don't have enough reputation yet, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

After one of your conditions evaluates as true, you break out of that if-block and don't evaluate following else-if/else statements. If you want the rest of them to evaluate you can make them if statements instead of else-if's.

Comment: Even though your explanation is fine, including a code example is even more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It's because firstly the computer checks for the first statement and then the others as you use the ELSE IF which means, to check the statement after the first one is false. Use IF for all instead.